# Django-allauth password reset link incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I've noticed that when I try to reset my password through django-allauth the link that is sent to me looks as follows:

`http://1/accounts/password/reset/key/6-3se-3805a3c50dfdbd446834/`

As you can imagine that link does not work. This is particularly strange because just moments before I was able to register a new account and the link that was emailed to me looked like so:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/confirm_email/c27b4410abf30f6aa52eef77895ef57e19d516e52b22969e4e6f713113187d06/
```

This one worked perfectly. I'm not sure why one email would be sending correct URL's while the other is sending broken URL's. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Looks like you disturbed the domain in sites. Go to `admin>sites` what domain name you see for the `SITE_ID` defined in settings?

Comment: Register a new user again just to check if the URL is correct or not? If not then probably it is because of reason I mentioned in first comment.